# python conditionals for cs class

Tags: python

Write a program that reads in three integers and prints which value is larger. Your program must be named biggest.py and be composed of a main function followed by a call to the main function

Here is what I wrote:

```
def main():
   a = int(input("the first integer? "))
   b = int(input("the second integer? "))
   c = int(input("the third integer? "))
   if a > b > c:
     print("the first integer is the largest")
   elif b > a > c:
     print("the second integer is the largest")
   elif c > a > c:        
     print("the third integer is the largest")
main()
```

However when i run the program is asks for the integers but doesnt give me any result after I input the integers

Comment: The third elif will never be triggered. You won't get output unless you enter integers in decreasing order or do mid, high, low.

Comment: There are 6 possible permutations for 3 numbers. Are you sure 3 conditions are enough?

Comment: Try running your code in the Python interpreter to determine errors in your logic. More importantly, I'd try to work this out on paper BEFORE jumping in to code.

Comment: If any of these answers helped you, you may select the one that helped most as the *accepted answer*

Answer (score 3):

Your conditions are too strict for what you want to accomplish. You should replace them with the following:

```
if (a > b and a > c):
elif (b > a and b > c):
elif (c > b and c > a):
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do if there's a tie for largest. As is, my method won't yield any output.

Comment: How about `if a == max(a,b,c)`?

Comment: @tobias_k That should work too, although from the looks of the question using the max function might be too much of a shortcut

Comment: Ouch, I thought the spec was to output the largest value. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to handle equality conditions or you want to print a message in any condition, you can try to handle equality condition in an `elif` block or print message in an `else` block:

```
answer = ""
if (a > b and a > c):
    answer = "a is the biggest: %s" % a
elif (b > a and b > c):
    answer = "b is the biggest: %s" % b
elif (c > b and c > a):
    answer = "c is the biggest: %s" % c
elif (a==b or a==c or b==c): 
    answer = "there is equality in some values"
```

But if you want to do a better approach, use `if` blocks and do check for every condition:

```
answer = []
if (a >= b and a >= c):
    answer.append(a)
if (b >= a and b >= c):
    answer.append(b)
if (c >= b and c >= a):
    answer.append(c)
#  Your answer list now contains the biggest value, or biggest values if two or more input have the same value and are the biggest within all inputs.
if len(answer) == 1:
    print "biggest values is: %s" % answer[0]
else:
    print "more than one values are the highest ones: %s" % answer[0]
```

Using `if` lets you check each possibility and using `>=` lets you handle equality conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to throw the values in a list, and sort it:

```
list_ = [a, b, c]
list_.sort(reverse=True)
print(list_[0])
```

Comment: If the OP needs the output in the form he mentioned, they'll still need to follow that up with some conditional stuff

Comment: `list_ = zip([a,b,c],['first','second','third']); print 'the {} number is largest'.format(sorted(list_,reverse=True)[0][1])`